# Ninject + Web ApI 2.Custom FilterProvider

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject

I have a problem with adding of custom FilterProvider in ASP WebAPI 2.
The problem is when I am adding my own FilterProvider and trying to delete other FilterProviders I can't delete them.

Here piece of code:

```
var providers = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetFilterProviders();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Clear(typeof(IFilterProvider));
             GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(typeof(IFilterProvider), new ExcludeFilterProvider(providers));
```

After I clear all services I suppose to have clear list of filter providers but when I call GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetFilterProviders() after clear method I get all list with all these providers if I don't call Clear method. 
I use Ninject as a DI container and it provides his own FilterProviders, DefaultFilterProvider and NinjectFilterProvider and I can't remove them.

Could you help me with it? Maybe need more info.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and it turned out I didn't need to actually remove these filter providers. Instead, I simply called:

`kernel.Rebind<IFilterProvider>().To<CustomFilterProvider>();`

in my Ninject start up call.

For some reason Bind did not do the job (it did add my filter provider, but the list of filters being returned was duplicated - I can only assume that the default provider was being left in place).

Hope that helps you!